# Debugging C++ program that reads external files in visual studio code

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a C++ program that reads some text files from a subdirectory located in the source code folder. The problem is that, the path that I've written in the program is relative and vs code outputs the debug program in `/tmp/` directory, which is then unable to read those files. Is there some way of working around it except for giving the absolute path of text files to the program?

Comment: Configure the path where the debug program is created. This should be configurable in tasks.json and launch.json. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) is VSCode's page for configuring the debugger.

Comment: How will you find that file "in production"?

Comment: @Vlad Fernstein Why would I do debugging in production;)?

Comment: Change the CWD of your program when run from the IDE.

Comment: @ArpitBhadauria I am saying that you need a way to find your external file regardless of the "source code folder". Using that is not sensitive to the changes in the location of your executable

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the working directory for Debugging in the Configuration Properties, So that you can access the file required using relative path.

In project properties window `Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory` update this to the desired path.